Replay buffer in StableBaselines3 for a Gymnasium environment
I'm creating a customized replay buffer class based on ReplayBuffer from stable_baselines3.common.buffers, using a gymnasium environment instead of the gym environment.
The return value of the env.step function is:
(state, reward, terminated, truncated, info) 

In the model.collect_rollouts function found in off_policy_algorithm.py, the code uses:
new_obs, rewards, dones, infos = env.step(actions)

When I run the cartpole-v1 the learning is indeed running.
I'm curious about how the learning code operates with this setup.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to develop a custom replay buffer for a Gymnasium environment?
